# Cannot enable Zip extension in Cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cpanel, pear

I am developing a Wordpress website which requires zip extension to process data. But I am not able to get Zip extension working. I sought many solutions online to fix this problem, almost all of them said that I have to enable zip extension from the Cpanel of the server by changing the php version or using EasyApache from WHM. But I cannot find any of these options in my cpanel. I have also installed Archive_Zip from PHP PEAR package manager but still no luck. Following is the information about my server:

Cpanel : 4.0 (build 36),
Apache Version  2.4.27,
PHP Version     5.6.31

How can I solve this issue ?
I have attached the picture of WHM interface please see.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In WHM go to `Software -> EasyApache4 -> Customize Profile` (applies to your current installed settings/packages). Go to **PHP Extensions**, select **All** for **Page size**, then enable the packages containing **ZIP** for all the php versions available there. Click on **Next** or **Review**, wait for WHM to prepare the packages and check the dependencies and then click on **PROVISION** and wait for WHM to install the required packages.

Then restart Apache (either via WHM or from the console) and you should have a working php-zip extension/module for all your installed php versions.

At the end it should look something like this:

```
[2017-08-23 16:52:15 +0300] info [xml-api] Service Status
[2017-08-23 16:52:15 +0300] info [xml-api] apache_php_fpm restarted successfully.
[2017-08-23 16:52:15 +0300] info [xml-api]  
[2017-08-23 16:52:15 +0300] info [xml-api]   Verifying  : ea-php70-php-zip-7.0.22-1.1.2.cpanel.x86_64                  1/3 
[2017-08-23 16:52:15 +0300] info [xml-api]   Verifying  : ea-php56-php-zip-5.6.31-2.2.3.cpanel.x86_64                  2/3 
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api]   Verifying  : ea-php55-php-zip-5.5.38-23.23.3.cpanel.x86_64                3/3 
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api] Installed:
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api]   ea-php55-php-zip.x86_64 0:5.5.38-23.23.3.cpanel                               
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api]   ea-php56-php-zip.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.2.3.cpanel                                 
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api]   ea-php70-php-zip.x86_64 0:7.0.22-1.1.2.cpanel                                 
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api] Finished Transaction
[2017-08-23 16:52:16 +0300] info [xml-api] Leaving Shell
```

Of course, that's from my cPanel dev server, in your case it might look different but that's a default cPanel/WHM install.

Comment: There is no option of software in WHM. I have edited my question and attached the picture for reference.

Comment: Then just look for EasyApache4. If you do not have it then you have to switch from EasyApache3 to EasyApache4 or compile apache + php from source (to include zip as well). But I recommend you switch to EA4

Comment: How can I get EasyApache4 installed in WHM ?

Comment: I suggest you read cpanel documentation first. There is pretty easy to follow and understand!